# call Swift function with completion handler in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift, react-native

**I have a react native app. I am trying to bridge react native with ios:**

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(getUserProfile:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback) {
  Cosmote *cosmote = [[Cosmote alloc] init];
  NSString * x;
  NSString * str;
  x = [cosmote getUserProfileWithCompletionHandler:^(NSString* string){string}]
  callback(@[x]);
}
```

**In Cosmote.swift I have the function:**

```
@objc
  open func getUserProfile(completionHandler: @escaping (_ s: String) -> ()) {
    let x = UserDetailsManager.self;
    x.getUserDetails(completionBlock: {data in
      print("got user Details")
      var json:String = "{\"data\": {\"guid\": \"\(data.guid)\", \"email\": \"\(data.email)\", \"username\": \"\(data.username)\", \"firstName\": \"\(data.firstname)\", \"lastName\": \"\(data.lastname)\", \"otePortalStatus\": \"\(data.otePortalStatus)\", \"otePortalisCorporate\": \"\(data.otePortalisCorporate)\", \"otePortalUserLevel\": \"\(data.otePortalUserLevel)\", \"otePortalAuthenticationLevel\": \"\(data.otePortalAuthenticationLevel)\", \"otePortalPIN\": \"\(data.otePortalPIN)\", \"otePortalEbppActivationDate\": \"\(data.otePortalEbppActivationDate)\", \"otePortalEbppEcareNumber\": \"\(data.otePortalEbppEcareNumber)\", \"otePortalEbppStatus\": \"\(data.otePortalEbppStatus)\", \"otegroupPasswordDate\": \"\(data.otegroupPasswordDate)\", \"otegroupStatus\": \"\(data.otegroupStatus)\", \"otegroupPasswordExpiration\": \"\(data.otegroupPasswordExpiration)\", \"otegroupPasswordReset\": \"\(data.otegroupPasswordReset)\", \"otegroupRegistrationDate\": \"\(data.otegroupRegistrationDate)\", \"otegroupAlternativeEmail\": \"\(data.otegroupAlternativeEmail)\", \"otegroupAlternativeMSISDN\": \"\(data.otegroupAlternativeMSISDN)\", \"imageURL\": \"\(data.imageURL)\"}}"
      completionHandler(json);
    }, onError: {_ in
      print("did not get user Details")
      completionHandler("{}");
    })
  }
```

**At first function in line:**

```
x = [cosmote getUserProfileWithCompletionHandler:^(NSString* string){string}]
```

**I got the errors:**

> Assigning to 'NSString *__strong' from incompatible type 'void'
>
> Incompatible block pointer types sending 'void (^)(NSString
>   *__strong)' to parameter of type 'NSString * _Nonnull (^ _Nonnull)(NSString * _Nonnull __strong)'

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call your "callback" from inside the methods completionHandler.
This should work for you:

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(getUserProfile:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback) {
   Cosmote *cosmote = [[Cosmote alloc] init];
   [cosmote getUserProfileWithCompletionHandler:^(NSString* string){
      callback(string)
   }];
}
```

Comment: I keep getting the error: Incompatible block pointer types sending 'void (^)(NSString *__strong)' to parameter of type 'NSString * _Nonnull (^ _Nonnull)(NSString * _Nonnull __strong)'

Comment: @billysk in the same line?

Comment: Yes, and the character ^ gets underlined

Comment: Ok :D I was hardly thinking were the problem is :D Then please accept the answer ;)